# Why is my nested component rebuilding itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, custom-component, rerender

I'm trying to build a custom slider based off the native input/range element. The summarized code looks something like this:

```js
const Slider = ({ className, backgroundColor, ...inputAttributes }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(5);

  const handleSliderChange = event => {
    setValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const SliderElement = () => (
    <input value={value} onChange={handleSliderChange} {...inputAttributes} />
  );

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      <SliderElement />
      <p>
        <Display>{value}</Display>
      </p>
    </>
  );
};
```

It's called like this:

```js
<Slider type="range" min={1} max={10} step={1} />
```

> Full running code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/000qm47pjw
>
> *w/ nested SliderElement component*

With the code above, I can only move the slider one step at a time (I have to "unclick" the slider and click on it again for the next step). I suspect it's because `SliderElement` is being rerendered every time I move the slider.

However...

If I skip  `SliderElement` altogether and put the `<input...` directly into the JSX returned, it works flawlessly.

> Full running code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5469y582yn
>
> *w/o nested SliderElement component*

---

Why is `SliderElement` rerendering every time I use it (assuming that's the case)?

How can I keep `<input...` wrapped in a nested component, and still be able to provide a buttery smooth experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinguish these two:

```
var aReactElement = <input />
var aReactComponent = () => <input />
```

A react component is responsible to decide if it should re-render the react elements it manages. It works under one premise, the component object *instance* should remain the same in order to serve as a ref key to a piece of persisting state.

In your example, the `SliderElement` instance is constantly changing in every re-render of `Slider`, it's a new function everytime. Thus your DOM tree is constantly unmounting then mounting the `<input />` element.

Instead of making `SliderElement` a component, you can make it an element.

```
const SliderElement = (
    <input value={value} onChange={handleSliderChange} {...inputAttributes} />
  );

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {SliderElement}
      <p>
        <Display>{value}</Display>
      </p>
    </>
  );
```